# Pusher receive event with null values

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher

I'm using laravel 5.8 version. I'm sending a message to pusher but put pusher receive event {"message": null}.
Here is my broadcasting.php file

```
'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
//                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
//                'useTLS' => true,
                'cluster' => 'ap2',
                'useTLS' => true
            ],
        ],
```

There is my chatevent.php file.

```
 namespace App\Events
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;
    use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class ChatEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $message;
    public $user;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message, User $user)
    {
        $this->$message = $message;
         $this->$user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

There is my bootstrap.js file.
    import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

```
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    // broadcaster: 'pusher',
    // key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    // cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    // encrypted: truebroadcaster: 'pusher',
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
        key:'REDACTED',
        cluster: 'ap2',
        encrypted: true
});
```

My controller function where I'm sending message to pusher.

```
public function send()
    {
        $message = 'hello';
        $user = User::find(Auth::id());

        event(new ChatEvent($message, $user));
    }
}
```

How to fix it????

Comment: I have edited your question to remove your API key, however I would recommend that you rotate your app keys to prevent unauthorised access.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are listening for the event?
Is the message content correct when inspected in the Pusher Debug Console (available through the app dashboard)?

Comment: pusher debug console
{
  "message": null,
  "user": null
}

Comment: protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\ChatEvent' => [
            'App\Listeners\ChatListner',
        ],
    ];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you write the constructor of your event class wrong.
Here you put extra `$` before `message` and `user` variable

```php
    public function __construct($message, User $user)
    {
        $this->$message = $message;
        $this->$user = $user;
    }
```

It should be like following one.

```php
    public function __construct($message, User $user)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->user = $user;
    }
```